# Beta Testing Android Apps

Tags: android, beta-testing

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IeaPoL7qoo) to see how I can send the app just to my highly-skilled beta testers (friends). I uploaded the APK to the "Beta Testing" tab of the Google Play Developer Console. However, since I am new, I do not know what to do next. I have a Google+ Community to whom this app is to be made available.

Please tell me what to do next to make the app available just to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to invite your highly-skilled beta testers to the Google+ Community.
They'll receive a email asking them to join the beta-testing community for your app.
Then, they can go to Google Play and download the beta.

Comment: They did join. They tell me that that they cannot find it. Do I have to use the "Promote To Prod" button?

Comment: Yes @LittleChild, but `prod` in Beta session. You will se some like "In Beta" label when you do it.