# Android Test Beta Apk from URL without Email invitation

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, beta-testing

I am uploading a Beta apk on play store, but I want to download that apk form URL for a user who visited my website.

I know only one way to download that apk through invitation. but I don't want to invite without Email address invitation from URL my website user able to download a Beta apk.

is this possible in android?

[Beta Testing Android Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779829/beta-testing-android-apps)

[How to add TestFlight beta app invitation from email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812863/how-to-add-testflight-beta-app-invitation-from-email)

https://bbvaopen4u.com/en/actualidad/beta-testing-how-developers-test-applications-android-and-ios

In IOS this is possible. Is any alternation for android?

https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/07/testflight-public-link-wwdc/

Answer (score 0):

The user always will have to opt-in. However you can create an "open" test which means you don't have to list the users by email address.

[The help page for this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213) - it sounds like you want an open test.

Comment: I want Beta Apk download only for my website user not for everyone. is this possible from url user saw apk from google store install option in Beta version